# Ulam's Conjecture, Graph isomorphism, Application

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Here is a short takeout on Ulam's Conjecture:
[image: img]
On the Wikipedia page it say it has been proven up to n=11.

Now the Question: 
If I have to check for the Isomorphism, does this mean, if I take out an Vertex x in Graph one and then show that for all vertices in Graph two it is impossible to get G-x, then they could not be isomorphic? As long I am have less the 11 edges. Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take out a vertex from the first graph, leaving $G-x$, but you can't find any isomorphism between $G-x$ and $H-y$ for any $y \in V(H)$, then $G$ and $H$ are definitely not isomorphic. (If there were an isomorphism $\phi$, then $H - \phi(x)$ would be isomorphic to $G-x$.)

Ulam's conjecture addresses the converse of this principle, and you don't need it to answer your question.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding ulan'c conjecture. in my opnion it says , if i remove a vertex, the iduced graph is not in deck of the other then they are not isomorphic.

Comment: @thetha Consider the statements $(P)$ "graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic" and $(Q)$ "the sets $\{G-x:x\in V(G)\}$ and $\{H-y:y\in V(H)\}$ are essentially the same" (the 'essentially' referring to isomorphism). Then it should be clear that
$$(P) \implies (Q),$$
which is pertinent to your question. Ulam's conjecture states that
$$(Q) \implies (P).$$

Comment: @thetha I should have written multisets rather than sets in my comment above, since we should count multiplicity. Anyway, does my explanation make sense, or would you like me to answer in more detail?

Comment: I think i get your point. But i cant realy prove that "all" the multisets are same. I was thinking to use it to proove that they are not isomorphic. For Example one graph is allways connected after removing any point, the other is not. The I could say, by Ulan's Conjecture, they are not isomorphic! Cant I?

Comment: @thetha If two graphs are isomorphic, then they are essentially the same object. Take $G$ to be the cycle $C_5$, for example, and suppose that $H$ is isomorphic to $G$. Then $H$ is also (a different copy of) $C_5$, and both graphs should behave the same way. Deleting any vertex of $G$ results in the path $P_4$; similarly, deleting any vertex of $H$ leaves $P_4$. Now, suppose we had a third graph $J$ on five vertices, and suppose that for some vertex $v$, it turns out that $J-v$ is *not* isomorphic to $P_4$. Then $G$ and $J$ are not isomorphic to each other. You don't need Ulam for this!

Comment: @thetha Now suppose we have another graph $L$ on five vertices, with the property that $L - v \cong P_4$ for any $v \in V(L)$. Is it necessarily the case that $G$ and $L$ are isomorphic? This is much harder to say, but Ulam's conjecture proposes that the answer is yes.

Comment: @thetha Also, note that since Ulam's Conjecture remains unproven (being a conjecture), then if you use it in a proof, your proof is conditional. That is, you can't just say "By Ulam's Conjecture, ...", but rather, "By Ulam's Conjecture, *assuming it is true*, then ..."